# Snowflake stored procedure queries not showing up in Query Profiler

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake stored procedure which is running for 8 hrs. Upon checking the query profiler to see which query is running long I just see a single entry for the call stored procedure statement.

[image: Query Profiler]

However, Through the logs I know that an insert statement is running which is like:

```
insert into Snowflake_table 
    select * 
    from External_table(over S3 bucket)
```

I want to check and find out why reading from external table is taking lot of time but the insert query is not showing up in the Query profiler. I have tried querying the information_schema.Query_history but its not showing another query running apart from the call stored procedure statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table(information_schema.Query_history_by_warehouse('ANALYTICS_WH_PROD')) 
WHERE execution_status = 'RUNNING'
ORDER BY start_time desc;
```

Please suggest how to find the bottleneck here

Comment: "through the logs I know..." - is the insert statement logging something to a certain table and you checked there or how do you know?

Comment: @Marcel - yes , the procedure logs all the queries into a log table before firing them

Answer (score 0):

Docs is stating that Queries on INFORMATION_SCHEMA views do not guarantee consistency with respect to concurrent DDL: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html

This means that it is possible that your insert-statement is running but is not shown as a result of your query. It could be included but it's not a must.

You could now change the filter to `execution_status IN 'success', 'failed'` and check again after the procedure finished.

Comment: I had to kill the session as it kept on running. However, I am still not able to see any entry of insert statement in query profiler or information_schema.Query_history. I ran the same procedure in my Dev env and able to see the insert and other queries which are in the procedure in Query profiler apart from the call store_proc entry. Wondering if there is any setting to turn on for this to happen.

Comment: This issue got resolved. It was due to missing MONITOR privilege, able to see all the queries fired by the stored proc in query profiler